# skips focus for TextView, to the next EditText (android)

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext, textview, focus

I have something of a registration form. 
All form fields inside it are `EditTexts`, but one is a `TextView`, that opens a `DatePicker` on click. 
So , I have something like :

```
1. editText1
2. textView(Datepicker)
3. editText3
```

After inserting a text in `edittext1` and pressing 'next' , it focuses on `edittext3`, rather than on `textview` (and opening the datepicker).

I tried setting `focusable`/`focusableInTouchMode` attributes in the textView's xml but it didn't help.

Comment: Show us the code for the layout and the activity of fragment of the registration page

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:clickable="true"` for the textView.

Comment: it doesn't focus on edittext3 now, but it doesn't seem to focus on the textview either cus it doesn't open the date picker

Comment: that is with 'focusable' attribute I mean. Without it clickable=true makes no change.